# python sort csv column as integer

Tags: python, sorting, csv

Trying to sort a csv integer column but it get sorted alphabetically.

This sorts alphabetically not numerically

```
sortedChanels = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(4), reverse=False)
```

Tried

```
sortedChanels = sorted(reader, key=lambda t: int(t(4)))
```

get error

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: just to be clear the csv column is a int but is getting sorted as alpha.

Comment: Looks like `t` is a list - your `t(4)` should be `t[4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sortedChanels = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[4]), reverse=False)
```